# Validate datetime inside a t-sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to validate a date inside a social security number checking function. The date format it should accept is `ddmmyyyy`, for example 01012000 (first of Jan, 2000).

I have tried converting this string into `yyyy-mm-dd`, and using `IsDate()` function, but the problem is that sometimes the datetimeformat of SqlServer might be something else like dmy, and I cannot use the "set DateFormat ymd" inside a function because it gives this error:

`Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET COMMAND' within a function.`

Also tried a `try .. catch` block but with the same results.

So I need a way to validate `datetime`, regardless of the SqlServer dateformat, in a user function.

Comment: `yyyymmdd` is settings independent. Why are you passing dates around as strings anyway though? Can't your application validate correctness and convert to appropriate datatype before it gets to the DB?

Comment: I'm trying to validate Finnish social security numbers which already are in database. And in that format it's always ddmmyy

Comment: So converting the string to `yyyymmdd` instead of `yyyy-mm-dd` and using `isdate` should work.

Comment: Yes it should, and that's what i did and what works when dateformat and language settings of the database are set to US format, but when database default language and datetime format is something else like scandinavian format (dd.mm.yyyy), then the IsDate() Function returns "not valid". I'd like to have a function which checks a date whatever the database's default format is, like DateTime.ParseExact would do in c#

Comment: Can you provide an example string in that format that returns unexpected results? `SET LANGUAGE Swedish; SELECT ISDATE('20010606'),ISDATE('20012906'),ISDATE('20010629')` works as expected for me (middle invalid other two valid)

Comment: @Martin Smith Thanks a thousand times! I tested your example and the problem was that ISDATE('2001.06.29') returns different results than ISDATE('20010629'). The latter doesn't seem to get infected by database default format! Thanks! How can i mark your comment as accepted answer?!?

Comment: `ISDATE` will accept many date formats.  For example `2012-12-31` is always accepted.  So it's not a strong enforcement of `ddmmyyyy`.  To accept @MartinSmith's answer, ask him to post it as an answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: Yes it accepts many formats, but it seems like YYYYMMDD is the only one not affected by DATEFORMAT:

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT ymd; 
SELECT ISDATE('2005-05-22'),ISDATE('20050522') 

SET DATEFORMAT dmy; 
SELECT ISDATE('2005-05-22'),ISDATE('20050522')
-- the first has different result on both queries, latter is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like

`SELECT ISDATE('2005-05-22')` is affected by `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` and returns zero

but

`SELECT ISDATE('20050522')` is not affected even when dateformat is `dmy`, so this one can be used independently from any dateformat used as default by database.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code will try to convert the input.  It first changes the string to a German time format `dd.mm.yyyy` with [convert format 104](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  It uses `begin try` to suppress any error during the conversion.

If it succeeds, the date is in `@output_dt`.  If it fails, `@output_dt` will be `null`.

```
declare @input_str varchar(25)
declare @output_dt date
set @input_str = '31122011'

if len(@input_str) >= 8
    begin
    declare @german_str varchar(25)
    select  @german_str = substring(@input_str, 1, 2) + '.' + 
                          substring(@input_str, 3, 2) + '.' + 
                          substring(@input_str, 5, 4)

    begin try
        select  @output_dt = convert(date, @german_str, 104)
    end try
    begin catch
    end catch
    end

select  @output_dt
```

If you can't use `begin catch`, you could create a table with valid dates.  This example creates a table called `ValidDates` with dates from 1900 to 2100:

```
if object_id('ValidDates') is not null
    drop table ValidDates
create table ValidDates (date_str varchar(8), dt date)
go
truncate table ValidDates

declare @start_dt date
declare @end_dt date
set @start_dt = '1900-01-01'
set @end_dt = '2100-01-01'

; with  cte as
        (
        select  @start_dt as dt
        union all
        select  dateadd(day, 1, dt)
        from    cte
        where   dt < @end_dt
        )
insert  ValidDates
        (date_str, dt)
select  replace(convert(varchar(10), dt, 104),'.','')
,       dt
from    cte
option  (maxrecursion 0);
```

You can then check for a valid date like:

```
select @output_dt = dt from ValidDates where date_str = @input_dt
```

Comment: begin try is unfortunately out of option because it cannot be used inside a userdefined sql-function (gives error "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator")

Comment: Creating a lookup table would definitely work, i'll give you points for that, but the solution sounds like killing a butterfly with atomic bomb to me.. :)